# Swift Project Crashing with EXC_BREAKPOINT error

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

In my **Swift** project, I have a `TabBarController` that has a navigation bar at the top and one of the buttons is a search button. When the search button is pressed, it loads another view controller that allows the user to search a list of cities.

In the second view there is a cancel button that is designed to allow the user to move back to the home screen, and when it's pressed, I get the `EXC_BREAKPOINT` error.

What's weird about this is that if I continue program execution in the debugger then the simulator behaves as expected moving forward, by performing the change from the search back to the main `TabBarController`. I can probably configure it so that it segues back to the home screen by itself, but then it would lack the tab bar buttons. Code and screenshots follow.

[image: This is the home screen, with the search button at the top.]
[image: This is the search screen and you can see the cancel button.]

```
@IBAction func cancelButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let tabVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabController") as TabBarController
    presentViewController(tabVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```